# I have imported the HttpWebRequest but visual studio is not recognizing the ContentLength properties

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

```
using System.Net.HttpWebRequest;
static string SendRequest(string method, string service, string postData)
{

    string responseString = null;
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(service);

    UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
    byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.ContentLength = data.Length;


    using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }

    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    }

    return responseString;
}
```

Comment: What does `but visual studio is not recognizing the ContentLength properties` mean? Any exception, unexpected result? Please show some effort to ask a understandable question.

Comment: red squiggles and error message is 'system.net.HttpWebRequest' does not contain the definition for 'ContentLength' and no extension method 'ContentLength' accepting a first argument of type 'system.net.HttpWebRequest' could be found ( are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?)

Comment: Compile time errors are the ones that can easily be  solved. I would recommend to read some c# documents to learn the tool you are using.

Comment: so i fixed that error. it seems like since im using a windows phone 8.1 app certain libraries cant be used such as the Console class. Console.Writeline() gives me same error method as above

Comment: Better use HttpClient class.....

Comment: I am trying to add a new class for my project but I cannot find HttpClient class. Do i need to implement my own.

Comment: `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`

Comment: my code was in a windows phone 8.1 app, i moved this over to a webApplication and all the errors disappeared

Answer (score 0):

Thew actual namespace is `System.Net` and so in your code it should be

```
using System.Net;
```

`HttpWebRequest` is the class name under that namespace. If you rather say `using System.Net.HttpWebRequest;` as in your posted code; VS will anyways throw red squiggly compilation error.

Comment: I just added the System.net and am still getting the red squiggly errors.